# assigning a column to be index and dropping it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As the title suggests I am reassigning a column as index but I want the column to appear only as index.

```
 df.set_index(df['col_name'], drop = True, inplace = True)
```

The documenatation as I understand it says that the above will reassign the column to the df and drop the initial column. But when I print out the df the column is now duplicated (as index and still as column). Can anyone point out where I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

You need only set column name `col_name` and parameter `inplace` in  [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). If use not column name, but column like `df['a']`, [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) doesn't drop column, only copy it:

```
print df
   col_name     a  b
0     1.255  2003  1
1     3.090  2003  2
2     3.155  2003  3
3     3.115  2004  1
4     3.010  2004  2
5     2.985  2004  3

df.set_index('col_name', inplace = True)
print df
             a  b
col_name         
1.255     2003  1
3.090     2003  2
3.155     2003  3
3.115     2004  1
3.010     2004  2
2.985     2004  3

df.set_index(df['a'], inplace = True)
print df
         a  b
a            
2003  2003  1
2003  2003  2
2003  2003  3
2004  2004  1
2004  2004  2
2004  2004  3
```

Comment: maybe it is just a python3 thing but 

  pprint.pprint(df)
     count   totalrow  year
  0               43     886802  2007
  1             2712    7242871  2008

  

df.set_index(df['year'],   inplace = True)

     count   totalrow  year
  year
  2007               43     886802  2007
  2008             2712    7242871  2008
  ...

Comment: well that did not come out right .. but suffice it to say that the column still remains!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Python 2.x, should work for you too (3.x)!

```
pandas.__version__
u'0.17.0'

df.set_index('col_name', inplace = True)
```

Comment: ok I see now, I was setting the whole df as the index. Thanks.